# Casperjs: How can I print http requests and responses?

Tags: javascript, http, casperjs

For debugging purporses I need to see the whole request: headers and data. How can I achieve this?

Comment: This isn't really a programming question, but there is a lot of info available in the browser's debugging tools. Failing that, [Fiddler 2](http://fiddler2.com/) will show *everything*.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher, I think you are missing the "CasperJS" part. If I can use Fiddler with a headless browser then I want to know how.

Comment: As long as Fiddler is running on the same machine as Casper, it can monitor all HTTP traffic.  Without knowing your setup I can't be specific, but look at the Network Configurations on this page: http://fiddler2.com/documentation/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureFiddler

Comment: Solved my problem! Consider writing an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Casper (well, actually PhantomJS) supplies two callbacks, one [when the resource is requested](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-requested.html) (where you can see headers being sent), and one when [response is received](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-received.html) (so you can see the headers the server replied with):

```js
var utils = require('utils');

var casper = require('casper').create();
casper.options.onResourceRequested = function(C, requestData, request) {
    utils.dump(requestData.headers);
};
casper.options.onResourceReceived = function(C, response) {
    utils.dump(response.headers);
};
```

(Using `utils` module is optional, it just gives nice human-readable formatting. Thanks to thelogix and AlanChavez for the suggestion in the comments.)

Comment: Maybe API has changed since your answer, but today this just prints "[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]". Using JSON.stringify fixes it for me: console.log(JSON.stringify(response.headers));

Comment: @thelogix that's more than likely a mistake that Darren overlooked, but any API that return an object `console.log` will only show an `[object Object]` output. Alternatively you can import `utils` and do `utils.dump` if you don't want to serialize the `response.header` output.

Comment: @thelogix @AlanChavez  More laziness than mistake :-) As people might be copy-and-pasting the above answer for quick troubleshooting, I updated it to use `utils.dump`.

Comment: You need to fix your brackets on the `dump` lines :)