# How to check Google Analytics for website using Casperjs?

Tags: google-analytics, casperjs

I want to check whether a site contains Google Analytics code or not.so how I do that is any method for it or it has any regular expression.

Comment: Don´t sure but maybe just test for the included script? this.exists('<script async="" src="//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script>'");

Comment: My suggestion is when you are loading the website using casperjs just listen to all the network calls made by that website and if the url contains "www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js" or whatever you are searching for then you have your answer. You can look here(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20924928/casperjs-how-can-i-print-http-requests-and-responses) how to listen to all the network requests in casperjs